# iOS - same .app name

Tags: ios

I've uploaded several .app's the the iTunes store, where the "executable" file (ie. filename.app) is the same.

What are the repercussion's of this on an actual device, when an actual person downloads both onto their iPad/Phone/Touch , and possibly is running both?

The best answer would be that it is inconsequential since the bundleID's store the .app in different respective folders, but I do need further insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name you give the app is irrelevant. All that matters is the bundle ID. These must be unique. From the iTunesConnect Developer's Guide:

> An identifier used by iOS and Mac OS X
>   to recognize any future updates to
>   your app. Your Bundle ID must be
>   registered with Apple and unique to
>   your app. Bundle IDs are app-type
>   specific (either iOS or Mac OS X). The
>   same Bundle ID cannot be used for both
>   iOS and Mac OS X apps.

Think about the consequences of the alternative. If I name my app `MyApp` and you name your app `MyApp`, then a user who bought both would be in trouble. The bundle ID is the unique identifier for each app. The name of the app is unique for convenience and to avoid confusion when purchasing an app, but the bundle identifier is unique to keep products from overwriting one another.